# What does a grayed-out build in TeamCity mean?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Some of our builds in TeamCity are grayed out, like they were disabled.

It often not obvious why. When I examine the details about the build, I find nothing noteworthy.

[image]

What exactly does this color signify?

Also: if, like in the picture above, there is a red build before the grayed out ones, the TeamCity status of the build configuration is red.

We are using TeamCity Enterprise 8.0.5 (build 27692)

Comment: This question is more about a software(or tool) than programming. Do you think it might be better suited to SuperUser?

Comment: @vidit I have now posted it to the TeamCity forum too https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5541004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of reasons that builds can show in the grey (personal build, cancelled build etc..).

I think the  most likely reason for the grey text shown in your screenshot is that the build is a history build. If this is the case, the 'Changes' column will say 'History'. What this means is that the build is older than one of the preceding builds and was built with out-of-date code.